# Redirecting to main domain when loading sub domain

Tags: magento, redirect, dns, subdomain

I have a domain and its sub domain.

In my main domain there have a Magento site that is in older version as 1.4.1.1, so i upgraded the site to 1.7.0.2 in my server.  That means we have no ssh login on client's server.  I downloaded the site from client server and uploaded in my local server. Then I upgraded the Magento site to the latest.

Then I created the sub domain in client's server and uploaded the upgraded Magento site in the sub domain.

But when I loaded sub domain as:

```
test.maindomain.com
```

then it redirects to the main domain.

What is the reason for this?

If there is any redirection process in that?

This is the htaccess in subdomain:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

How can I solve this?

If there is any solution for this?

**EDIT:**

If I removed the contents in `index.php` and replace with `test file now`.

Then I take the url as `test.maindomain.com` then it displays `test file now` in browser.

The content changed, after loading the sub domain not goes to main domain.

So what is the real problem here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the subdomain. You need a vhost that listen on your subdomain and put it on the correct directory.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Servername test.maindomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

**Edit:** If you will be redirected to the main page. Its possible that you programm redirect to the old domain.

Answer (score 0):

The redirection might come from various places, depending on how did you make a copy of the original project.
Doing a full copy of original magento directory including all cache files, you should **clean your** `var/cache` **directory**.

`rm -r var/cache/*` inside your subdomain magento direcory should do the trick or empty it with some other way you prefer.

If that does not help, you should also change **base_url in database**. This can also be done in various ways, but as a result you should change rows in `core_config_data` table. Command line method:

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://subdomain/' where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
update core_config_data set value = 'http://subdomain/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

[Extensive explanation and other options for changing base_url](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-change-magento-base-urls.html#sthash.z0Crk74D.dpuf)

Clearing browser cache might be needed also.